# Why reflect.ValueOf can not print out true value of int using Println in golang

Tags: reflection, go

```
func main() {
    var val interface{} = 11
    fmt.Println(reflect.ValueOf(val))   
}//print out : <int Value>
```

But after I pass string,like "Hello" to val,it will print out the string itself.
I notice that value struct has a method

```
func (v Value) String() string
```

It says that if v'type is not a string,it returns a string of the form "[T value]" where T is v's type,but,why not returning something like [int 11],I also know that I should append an Int() function to ValueOf() to get the actual value of val,but I do not understand the internal relationship between value struct,and String function and the Println function

Comment: Are you asking for the reasoning behind that design? or for a method you can use to print the value?

Comment: Yes,the reason of the design,thank you

Comment: Please have a careful look at all the document on http://golang.org expecially the FAQ, Effective Go, the Tour and the various blog posts.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not a Go author or anything, but I think the design is a product of three properties of Go:

- Getters commonly leave off `Get` [source](http://golang.org/doc/effective_go.html#Getters)
- The fmt package uses a `String` method if it is available. [source](http://golang.org/pkg/fmt/#Stringer)
- Interfaces are satisfied implicitly

The first leads to the methods like `Int`, `Float`, `Bool`, `String` etc. All of these methods will panic if called on a value of the wrong type, except `String`. This is because `String` would be used by fmt, and likely many other packages to get a string representation of the value, and it is surely unreasonable for only string values to be printable. Arguably there should be another method which returns the underlying string instead of `String`, but that would mean less consistency in the api, so they chose the lesser of two evils.

[Reflect Documentation](http://golang.org/pkg/reflect/#Value.String)

Comment: var val interface{} = "Hello"  , fmt.Println(reflect.ValueOf(val).String()),it is surely to get the right value of val,so,String() method is used the same way as Int().What makes me confused is why it yields the same value even I don't use String() method?Thank you

Comment: Are you asking why `Println` prints the same value?  That's because `Println` checks to see if its arguments conform to the `fmt.Stringer` interface, and calls their `String` method to format them for printing if so.  `reflect.Value` conforms to this interface, as said in the answer.

Comment: The fmt package uses a type assertion to determine whether the value you pass has a String method. If it does, it will be called. So whether you call String or not, the two cases are equivalent.

Comment: @Logiraptor oh right,this is the mechanism behind the sense

Answer (score 2):

Go 1.5 (August 2015) should allow you to print the actual value of a `Reflect.Value()` argument.
See [review 8731](https://go-review.googlesource.com/#/c/8731/) and [commit 049b89d](https://github.com/golang/go/commit/049b89dc6f6b6f1001672dd5456197b74a97cbec) by [Rob Pike (`robpike`)](https://github.com/robpike):

> ### `fmt`: treat `reflect.Value` specially - as the value it holds
>
> When a `reflect.Value` is passed to `Printf` (etc.), `fmt` called the `String` method, which does not disclose its contents.
>   To get the contents, one could call `Value.Interface()`, but that is illegal
>   if the `Value` is not exported or otherwise forbidden.
>
> This CL improves the situation with a trivial change to the `fmt` package: when we see a `reflect.Value` as an argument, we treat it exactly as we treat a `reflect.Value` we make inside the package.
>   This means that we always print the contents of the `Value` as if *that* was the argument to `Printf`.
>
> This is arguably a breaking change but I think it is a genuine improvement and no greater a break than many other tweaks we have made to formatted output from this package.