# Print all values in map recursively in Go

Tags: go

Suppose I have a map of this type:

```
var results map[string]interface{}
```

The values can be anything, even another map. How would I print all the values? If the value is an array, I want to print each item in the array individually. If it is another map, I want to recursively call the same function on the map.

Comment: Do you just want to print it to inspect the data within?

Comment: Have you tried the various outputs provided by the `fmt` package? Does Marshaling to json work for you?

Comment: @sberry I don't want to inspect the data within, I just want to compare the values of two arbitrary json hashes and print out the intersection.

Comment: @JimB yup, I am marshalling from json to this format, because the data is arbitrary.

Comment: @VladtheImpala your comment and the question don't match

Comment: i don't really know the specifics of the problem you're trying to solve, and i might be wrong, but usually having to use reflection is a sign of bad design. I really believe that you should implement the proper interface functions on your types (like String()) and then sure, if at some point you are forced to use an interface{} receiver for them, do it, but having concrete implementation on the types will produce the intented behaviour on each in stuff like printing etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I shamelessly ripped this from a site some time ago:

```
import (
    "fmt"
    "reflect"
    "strings"
)

/*
InspectStruct prints the guts of an instantiated struct. Very handy for debugging
usage: InspectStruct(req, 0) -> prints all children
*/

func InspectStructV(val reflect.Value, level int) {
    if val.Kind() == reflect.Interface && !val.IsNil() {
        elm := val.Elem()
        if elm.Kind() == reflect.Ptr && !elm.IsNil() && elm.Elem().Kind() == reflect.Ptr {
            val = elm
        }
    }
    if val.Kind() == reflect.Ptr {
        val = val.Elem()
    }

    for i := 0; i < val.NumField(); i++ {
        valueField := val.Field(i)
        typeField := val.Type().Field(i)
        address := "not-addressable"

        if valueField.Kind() == reflect.Interface && !valueField.IsNil() {
            elm := valueField.Elem()
            if elm.Kind() == reflect.Ptr && !elm.IsNil() && elm.Elem().Kind() == reflect.Ptr {
                valueField = elm
            }
        }

        if valueField.Kind() == reflect.Ptr {
            valueField = valueField.Elem()

        }
        if valueField.CanAddr() {
            address = fmt.Sprintf("0x%X", valueField.Addr().Pointer())
        }

        fmt.Printf("%vField Name: %s,\t Field Value: %v,\t Address: %v\t, Field type: %v\t, Field kind: %v\n",
            strings.Repeat("\t", level),
            typeField.Name,
            //valueField.Interface(),
            address,
            typeField.Type,
            valueField.Kind())

        if valueField.Kind() == reflect.Struct {
            InspectStructV(valueField, level+1)
        }
    }
}

func InspectStruct(v interface{}, level int) {
    InspectStructV(reflect.ValueOf(v), level)
}
```

Comment: thank you, the key turned out to be `reflect.TypeOf(value).Kind() == reflect.Map`.

Comment: @VladtheImpala Note: printing a Reflect.Value() will be easier with Go 1.5. See http://stackoverflow.com/a/29668359/6309.

Comment: Can you point out how it should be used? When I use the `InspectStruct(myMap, 1)` it gives me the error `reflect.Value.NumField on map Value`

Comment: @bat it should be used like that, but it is not 100% failsave. I have had to disable some lines from time to time to make this work for particular payloads.

Answer (score 0):

Using %v on fmt.Printf will traverse the inner maps and print the elements
too by calling String() on each. Now if you want to change this default printing on an inner type you just have to implement String() on that type. in the following example i created a version of []int that prints one int per line.

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "strings"
)

type OnePerLineInt []int

func (ip OnePerLineInt) String() string {
    var ret []string
    for _, a := range ip {
        ret = append(ret, fmt.Sprintf("Item: %v\n", a))
    }
    return strings.Join(ret, "")
}

func main() {
    arr := &OnePerLineInt{1, 2, 3}
    arr1 := []int{4, 5 , 6}
    foo := make(map[string]interface{})
    bar := make(map[string]interface{})
    bar["a"] = "foobar1"
    bar["b"] = "foobar2"
    foo["1"] = arr
    foo["2"] = bar
    foo["3"] = arr1
    fmt.Printf("foo contents: %v\n", foo)
    fmt.Printf("bar is :%v\n", bar)
}
```

prints:

```
foo contents: map[1:Item: 1
Item: 2
Item: 3
2:map[a:foobar1 b:foobar2] 3:[4 5 6]]
bar is :map[a:foobar1 b:foobar2]
```

http://play.golang.org/p/kc6xm7dHwx